# SQL server performance when table has many columns

Tags: sql-server

My question is about performance on SQL server tables.

Assume I have a table that has many columns, for example 30 columns, with 1 column indexed. This table has approximately 30,000 rows.

If I perform a select that selects the indexed column, and one more, for example this:

```
SELECT IndexedColumn, column1
FROM table
```

Will this be slower than performing the same select on a table that only has 2 columns, and doing a `SELECT * ...`

So basically, will the existence of the extra columns slow down the select query event if I am not retrieving the data from the extra columns?

Comment: If `column1` isn't part of your index, a `SELECT` with no `WHERE` will not use that index at all. It has to use the clustered index, and yes, scanning a clustered index of 30 columns is slower than scanning one of 2. That said -- any sufficiently beefy server will scan through 30.000 rows of anything in what is probably negligible time, so unless you're selecting all rows several times per second you're unlikely to notice. If `column1` *was* part of your index (that is, it's covering), then the clustered index isn't hit and the number of columns in the table is irrelevant. Consider `INCLUDE`.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a good [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be minor difference on the very end of the process as you don't have to print/pass the rest of information for the end client (either SSMS or other app).

When performing a read based on clustered index all of the column (without BLOB) are saved on the same page set so to read the data you have to access the same set of pages anyway.

You would see a performance increase if you would have a nonclustered index on the column list you are after as then they are saved in their own structure of data pages (so it would be less to read).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the default Clustered Index created by SQL server when defining the primary key on the table in both scenarios then no, there shouldn't be any performance difference between these two scenarios. Maybe worth just checking it out and generating an Actual Execution plan to see for yourself? -- Actually not sure above is true, as given this is rowstore, the first table wont be able to fit as many rows onto each page so will suffer more of an IO/Disk overhead when reading data.